# Can I specify a lifecycle callback that fires for all waterline models in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to add some auditing capability to my sails.js app. 
The `afterUpdate` lifecycle callback will give me the proper place to do what I need, but I'm hoping to avoid modifying every model to reference my new code.

Is there a way to specify an `afterUpdate` callback that will fire on all models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your required overrides into **config/models.js**

```
module.exports.models = {

  attributes: {},

  afterUpdate: function (valuesToUpdate, cb) {
    // add your logic here...
    console.log('yep, updated');
    cb();
  },
}
```

The idea is that then all your models obtain this implementation of the method by default. You can also add shared attributes, as given above (currently empty object).

Comment: @davepreston - could you please mark this as correct answer if it has resolved your issue - tested locally, i am confident this works.

Comment: accepted. sorry for the slow response. I was on vacation and couldn't verify. thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: @davepreston - hey np, thanks very much for accepting the answer, pleased it helped.