# Is it possible to get model definition in callback override in sails.js?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am working on something similar to [Can I specify a lifecycle callback that fires for all waterline models in sails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666236/can-i-specify-a-lifecycle-callback-that-fires-for-all-waterline-models-in-sails/34679600#34679600).

I'd like to be able to reference the model definition in the callback, but only the attributes and id are currently sent to the afterUpdate. Is there a way to determine which model I'm working with, other than adding 'type' as an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct scoping plus `this` will work in **config/models.js**.

```
module.exports.models = {

    attributes: { . . .},

    afterUpdate: function (model) {
        console.log(this.identity);  //model name that triggered callback
        console.log(this.definition); //model definition

        //logic . . .
    }
};
```